# TFS Follow Not Emailing

Tags: tfs

My searches have returned so many non-related results, I apologize.  My issue is simple, in TFS when I click "Follow" on an item, I would expect to be emailed when the item is changed, that's what the documentation seems to say. It's not happening. I do receive a notification when an item is assigned to me so email configuration is not the issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hi @soulTower, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to '**Project Settings**' > '**Notifications**' > '**+ New subscription**', and set up a custom notification subscription for '**Work**' > '**A work item is changed**'. Then to see if you can receive the notification email when the work item is changed.

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

Please click the [image] gear icon to check if the selected option is '**Subscribed**'.

[image]

For more details, you can see "[**Follow work**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/follow-work-items?view=azure-devops-2020)".

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had tried your suggestion previously and did receive an email when creating a specific subscription.  However I still do not receive one if I simply follow the item.  My team is using a workaround in creating a subscription for each task and adding the necessary addresses. However this is labor intensive when you have 50+ items to track and a large team. Clicking Follow would be ideal.

Comment: Hi @soulTower, I have updated my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: I don't have a hear next to my Following button.

Comment: Hi @soulTower, what is the version of your TFS server?